# Cant turn on firmware protection of windows defender

Tags: windows, windows-defender, windows-11

How to turn on firmware protection? I have Hyper-V enabled. There is no third party antivirus installed. Please help me

[image: Windows Security settings]

[Msinfo32.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL9bp.png)

[vbs info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSnH5.png)

Comment: You have disabled (more than likely) the diagnosis data or you are connected to a AD domain and a group policy is actually being applied to your machine

Comment: If your not sure what setting you disabled to caused the “this setting is managed …” my advice would be to perform a Windows Reset. If that still doesn’t work report the behavior as a bug.  You can [edit] your question to include the vital information necessary to answer your question

Comment: @Ramhound please give me the solution

Comment: Reset your installation and enable everything when prompted during the OBOE

Comment: @Ramhound does not work..Shows same

Comment: Sounds like a bug in that case.

Comment: At this point, since it's an Insider Preview build, I would perform a clean install of the current Windows 10 ISO then upgrade that to the current Insider Preview build of Windows 11.

Comment: did but still same

Comment: You never address my question with regards to the possibility your machine is connected to an AD domain.

Comment: no its not connected

Comment: So you performed a clean install of 21H1 and then upgraded that version to Windows 11, and after the upgrade, you had the same problem?  That does not make sense, "this setting is managed by your administrator" only happens for two reasons.  You have a required setting disabled or it's actually being managed by a group policy.  Post a screenshot of the group policy editor, showing the current status of `Disable Memory integrity switch`

Comment: I also need to know the current status of the [virtualisation-based security](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/images/enable-hvci-gp.png) as outline in the screenshot.  You also need to provide a screenshot of [System Information](https://www.virtualizationhowto.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Use-MSINFO32.EXE-to-verify-virtualization-based-security-in-Windows-10.png)

Comment: I have updated my problem...please check it

Comment: please help me @Ramhound

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue in Windows 11 Pro 22H2 and my guess is that the feature either can't be enabled because all prerequisites aren't met or because of malware; the "Firmware protection" feature is called "System Guard Secure Launch" by Microsoft at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-system-guard/system-guard-secure-launch-and-smm-protection and lists the system requirements in vague terms as "all the baseline requirements for System Guard, Device Guard, Credential Guard, and Virtualization Based Security".

The "Firmware protection" option doesn't even appear until using the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc) to enable the "Turn On Virtualization Security" policy. After a reboot, even with the "Secure Launch Configuration" option of that policy set to "Enabled", the corresponding registry key at Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\SystemGuard\Enabled set to "1", and the "System Information" app (msinfo32.exe) showing "Secure Launch" as being "Configured" ("Virtualization-based security Services Configured") under "System Summary", the "Firmware protection" option is still shown as being off.

If I reset the policy to "Not Configured" and the registry key Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\SystemGuard\Managed to "0" (which presumably corresponds to the yellow "This setting is managed by your system administrator." message), after a reboot, the "Firmware protection" toggle simply disappears again indicating that Windows wouldn't normally even offer the option to toggle the setting.